# How to best structure socket io code for multi rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

Dependency setup:

```
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0"
```

I have a react app that talks to my express js server. It uses socket io for real time client interaction.

**What is the best way to structure the code in express for multi rooms?**

Currently I have multiple clients that can connect to different rooms. Initially in my express js server I had global variables and everything worked fine for when multiple clients joined one room.

The problem of course, comes when there is another room with other clients, I am actually sharing the global variables between them. I know this is a problem (I was mainly doing a PoC initially). I have some ideas but wanted to know if there are best practices for structuring the code so that its good to use with different rooms.

For example, one idea I had is store a big dictionary where I have key = roomId, value = property bag of all the variables I need for that room
That should work but it didn't seem the cleanest of approaches.

Any ideas?

Also, is it a best practice to put all the code inside the main connection code?
i.e:

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on('join', (room) => {
    }
    ...
    socket.on('anotherEvent', (room) => {
    }
    ...
    socket.on('yetAnotherEvent', (room) => {
    }
  });
```

More specific example: 
Say I have this event and this global variable that I hold whose turn it is to play a game.

```
var playerTurnOrder = [];
var nextPlayer = 0;
  socket.on("Pass", () => {
    let room = getRoomForSocket(socket);
    nextPlayer++;
    io.to(socket.rooms[room]).emit("RefreshBoard", {
      board: board,
      pieceIntroduced: null,
      nextPlayer: playerTurnOrder[nextPlayer % 4]
    });
  });
```

Code above works fine when there is one room in play.
If there are two rooms (say with 4 clients in each room)
I now have a problem because i'm sharing the playerTurnOrder variable and the nextPlayer variable.

That is why I was thinking maybe I can hold a dictionary (or Map as suggested in comments) where key = room and value = more variables i want to hold..
That should work but was looking for people who have had similar struggles on how to structure socket io code in nodejs and with having multiple rooms (channels)

Comment: You'd' really have to show us your code for us to make a concrete suggestion on what to do.  Your words don't really describe what you're trying to do.  Also socket.io users don't "connect to a room" so that parts confuse.  They connect to a server and can join zero or more rooms.  Questions about how to structure code here really ought to show the relevant code.  If you have dynamic state associated with a room, there are a number of ways you can keep that state.  Please show some of your code so we can see what it is you're trying to keep track of and we can then make some suggestions.

Comment: ***one idea I had is store a big dictionary where I have key = roomId, value = property bag of all the variables I need for that room***.  That's perfectly fine way to do it.  Use a `Map()` object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll show some code